# How to install WHM/Cpanel over a vps with os ubuntu through Putty or SSH

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, cpanel, whm

I have a question related to WHM/Cpanel,

How can i install WHM/Cpanel over a vps with os ubuntu (16.04) through Putty or SSH.
i want someone who can tell me how i can do it.

Thanks in advance

@The next level coders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install cpnel in ubuntu. Centos 7 is the better option for cPanel. You can install cpanel in few steps by follow this official tutorial https://docs.cpanel.net/installation-guide/install/

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Server Computing, can you tell me which is the better alternative for the Ubuntu?

Comment: Developers are using all Operating systems, which one is comfortable for their development. Some apps working fine on some OS only. For example, cPanel working on centos only.

You have to check the requirements from the app provider.